# anaconda not recognised after updating environment variable linux

Tags: linux, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, redhat

I have installed anaconda on a linux red hat system by running the following command (on a <s>airgapped</s> remote system where I don't have sudo privileges or internet access).

`$bash Anaconda3-5.1.0.Linux-x86_64.sh`

This has installed anaconda in the directory `/home/myuser/anaconda3/`

The .bashrc file reads:

```
#added by Anaconda3 installer
. /opt/projectname/bin/setenv.sh
export PATH="/home/myuser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

When I run 
`$conda` or `$jupyter notebook`, I get `command not found`.

`$python` launches an old version of python which is not linked to anaconda.

If I run:

```
$bash jupyter notebook
```

from 
    `/home/myuser/anaconda3/bin/`

I get:

```
jupyter: line 4: import: command not found
jupyter: line 5: import: command not found
etc...
```

How can I get the system to run the correct version of python and successfully launch jupyter notebook?

EDIT: is the problem here that anaconda was installed in `/home/myuser` rather than `/usr/x` or `/opt/x`?

Comment: "*airgapped remote*" - Choose one.

Comment: haha, good point. sorry I meant, remote access is possible but no internet access (the sysadmins downloaded the installer file for me)

Comment: Did you log out and back in after modifying .bashrc?

Comment: yes, I tried that

Comment: What does `echo "$PATH"` say?

Comment: `echo/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory`

Comment: No buns in your path.

Comment: You failed at copy/paste (that is, you retyped the command and dropped the space after `echo`). But close enough.

Comment: I don't know what "sudo privileges" means, but if you're not root, why is `/sbin` in your path?

Comment: can't copy/paste from my rdp session :(

Comment: Try `. .bashrc` to load .bashrc manually. Does that update your PATH?

Comment: nothing happens with `. .bashrc` but `vi ~.bashrc` opens the file I was editing previously

Comment: The `.` sources it, so try echoing again.

Comment: How do you know nothing happened? Did you `echo $PATH` again or try to run `jupyter`?

Comment: my bad, `echo $PATH` now contains `/home/myuser/anaconda3/bin:`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `/sbin` in your path adds its contents to your completions as a potential sudoer. Since it's at the end of the path, it will never supersede commands that can be executed without `sudo`, however it will complete commands like `apt-get i`->`apt-get install` that will fail unlike `sudo apt-get install` or `apt-get help`. It should be benign.

Comment: ok so now everything is running fine, i am able to run `$jupyter notebook` and it launches correctly. thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on terminal

```
source /home/myuser/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

This will activate your anaconda python installation. (base) should appear in your terminal.

Now *jupyter notebook* should work.

**Note :** I did not append *anaconda3/bin* to the PATH variable as I wanted to keep my original python installation as default. I activate anaconda3 using the above command everytime I needed it.